# Untagged Questions?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed the existence of [untagged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) and figured it’d be a nice, editorial thing to do to at least give them the relevant system tags.

When I’d finished, I realized that I’d A. just bumped a whole bunch of questions, mostly long-since answered, to the top of the question list, and B. created a whole bunch of new tags that didn't exist for systems that have only ever had one question asked about them.

So my question is, is that how [untagged](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) should be handled? Or is it OK for things to be untagged, or at the least *left* untagged if they’ve been that way for a while? Does creating these singleton tags cause more problems than it solves?

Answer (score 4):

**To solve the problem, ask more questions in those respective tags.**

Singletons get deleted. This is annoying, but there's not much we can do about it. The only real solution is to ask real questions with those tags in them.

Under no circumstances are you to spam the front page retagging tens of old questions. As a general protocol 2-4 at any given time, and allow *at least* that many new things to percolate above them before continuing.

Comment: I did all of them because I forgot they'd bump to the top. There were "only" 10 but still. I did not know that about singletons.

Comment: Yeap. So now you, as saviour of those questions, can ask *additional* questions about them.

Comment: I know almost nothing about basically all of the systems in question. Never even heard of most of them.

Comment: You'd better find some copies of them & start reading, then.

Comment: It's not *that* heinous a sin to bump 10 questions for editing reasons. I've seen many of us experienced users do that at one point or another in the past (*I* certainly have), and we learned from the embarrassment. ;)